# Do not know why using "this" for checking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, this

I create an array called `Zombies` which includes all the **Game Object** in the scene. And I also create the foreach loop to check if the `Zombies` have attached `ZombieState.cs`. I'm following the book but it's not explaining clearly why we need `zState==this`.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ZombieState : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject[] Zombies = (GameObject[])GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject));
        foreach (GameObject go in Zombies)
        {
            ZombieState zState = go.GetComponent<ZombieState>();
            if (zState == null || zState == this)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The `this` keyword refers to the current instance of the class. In your case you check if `zState` is the same as the current instance of `ZombieState` game object. Your code looks incomplete, so without knowing what you want to do with found `zState` it is hard to say what should be the correct way of handling here. But it looks like your `ZombieState` should be a separate `Singleton` class and you should have a `Zombie` class that will be an actual `Zombie` game object